# Counter Strike free version upgraded to the Valve complete bundle but still showing free version on launch

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I got the Counter Strike free version, then I bought the Valve complete bundle so I could have the full version but when I launch the game it still says I have the free version. I don't want to rebuy the game, I have tried uninstalling the game and it did not work. How can I use the full version?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the data for the free version is still being used. I suggest uninstalling the game and reinstalling it. Just go to your library, right-click on CS and select Uninstall. Follow through and reinstall the game.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue. As of 6 December 2018, CSGO is completely free. If you want, you can purchase Prime Account status, but the full game is now free.